# JS libraries not working after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I have an Ajax call, that returns some HTML code. In this returned code, I have several dropdown boxes that use the [select2](https://select2.github.io/) JavaScript library among many others (company libraries, custom libraries, etc.)

Now, none of the libraries seems to work at all in the content retrieved from the Ajax call.

A solution to a similar problem can be solved by using the jQuery delegate method (according to other questions made), but in this case I cannot simply go into the select2 library (nor inside all the other ones for that matter) and replace everything with delegate.

What solutions can I implement in order to make the libraries work on the returned ajax content?

Comment: Using delegated event handlers is the right way for fixing the events that don't work. You will also need to initialise the Select2 plugin on any new elements appended within the callback of the AJAX request.

Comment: But I can't just edit all the external libraries I have and replace everything with delegate. It would break many of them as far as I know, not to mention the nightmare it would be to update for a newer version.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why you'd need to amend the libraries at all? Can you post an example of your code. Hopefully that would make the problem clearer.

Comment: *"none of the libraries seems to work at all in the content retrieved from the Ajax cal"* You might have to initialize the plugins on the new content.

Comment: What if I can't initialize the plugins because the process seems to be automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading html into the page via AJAX you will need to run the initialization function on the new html:

```
//from the docs
$('select').select2();
```

If you are using jQuery.load you can do it like this:

```
 //load the html into #result
 $( "#result" ).load( "demo.html", function() {
    //now use 'this' in the selection to search the new html and init select2
    $('select',this).select2();
 });
```

alternatively, to use delegate, you wait until after a click (or a custom event) and then initialize select2 again but I don't think you need to do that in this case.